# PySNMP MIB Query on HP Procurve Not Working

Tags: pysnmp

I am attempting to utilize PySNMP to query HP Procurve switches. So far, I have converted hpicfChassis.mib to HP-ICF-CHASSIS.py via mibdump.py, and confirmed this MIB is in the correct path. I have tried with and without the MibBuilder code, and still errors galore.

I am attempting to query SNMP values of hpicfSlotDescr, and other SNMP values within this MIB, and it just bombs with following error message:

pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: Instance index (0,) to OID convertion failure at object 'hpicfSlotDescr': ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647)), ValueRangeConstraint(1, 16)) failed at: "ValueRangeConstraint(1, 16) failed at: "0"" at Integer32

I've done a packet capture, and when using hpicfSlotDescr, which can return up to six values, the SNMP query never generates the request to the switch.

When querying a different SNMP value such as hpicfEntityIndex, which expects 1 return value, I see the request sent out, but the switch never replies. The community names in the script and on the switch match, and I'm just lost and wondering if what I'm trying to accomplish is feasible, and if so, what major components am I missing??

Thanks in advance!

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
from pysnmp.smi import builder

#MIBDIR = '/Python/Lib/site-packages/pysnmp_mibs'
#mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
#mibSources = mibBuilder.getMibSources() + (builder.DirMibSource(MIBDIR),)
#mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibSources)
#mibBuilder.loadModules('HP-ICF-CHASSIS')


errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('<comm name>', mpModel=1),
       UdpTransportTarget(('<ipv4 address>', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('HP-ICF-CHASSIS', 'hpicfSlotDescr', 0)))
)

if errorIndication:
print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, in accordance with your MIB definition, the table (to which `HP-ICF-CHASSIS::hpicfSlotDescr` column belongs to) does not allow zero as its index value. This is communicated in pysnmp exception:

```
ValueRangeConstraint(1, 16) failed at: "0"
```

Since pysnmp could not build the OID to query from your MIB symbol data, no packet was sent. So I'd try proper index values in range of 1..16 e.g.:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('HP-ICF-CHASSIS', 'hpicfSlotDescr', 1)))
```

Finally, you do not really need the manual MIB conversion step. As soon as you pass MIB name to the `ObjectIdentity` class, the latter will attempt to find ASN.1 source of this MIB on your local filesystem as well as at [this web site](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/) and compile it into Python behind the scenes. More information on this can be found in [pysnmp docs](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/api-reference.html#mib-variables).

Comment: That was the fix, much appreciated.